# Binding with the selection of an NSArrayController in another nib

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, model-view-controller, cocoa-bindings

I have two nibs:

1. Store.nib
2. Product.nib

Product.nib's File owner is a subclass of `NSViewController` which has a property `product` to which various controls are bound:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) SRProduct *product;
```

[image]

---

Store.nib has an `NSArrayController` object which has been bound to a property of `SRApplicationController`, which is this property:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSArray *products;
```

`SRApplicationController` has an outlet to that `NSArrayController` object.

[image]

---

In the `-[SRApplicationController init]` method I init an `SRProductController` object with the Product.nib nib. In `-[SRApplicationController awakeFromNib]` I add the view of the product controller to a view in Store.nib, and I bind the `productsArrayController` property (the outlet) of the `SRApplicationController` object to the `product` of the product controller:

```
- (id)init {
  if (self = [super init]) {
    self.productController = [[SRProductController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Product" bundle:nil];
  }

  return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib {
  [self.productView removeAllSubviews]; // this method is from a category
  [self.productView addSubview:self.productController.view];
  [self.productController.view setFrame:self.productView.bounds];

  [self.productsArrayController bind:@"selectedObjects" toObject:self.productController withKeyPath:@"product" options:nil];
}
```

---

When I run the app, I get no errors, no warnings, the console remains empty, the table view with all products in Store.nib shows all products and I can select them. The problem is that all fields in Product.nib are empty, but they **are** bound to the `product` property of the file owner. Can anyone help me with this problem? Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere there is some sample code that shows how to do this, I can't remember if is Apple code or from somewhere else. Basically what you need to do is have an array controller in each nib file. The array controller in the list style nib should be bound normally and it's array controller should be an accesible property. In the second nib file you need to bind the array controller's content as normal. You also need to make sure that the file's owner of this detail nib has a connection to the file's owner of the list nib. You then bind the sort descriptor for the detail array controller to `listController.arrayController.sortDescriptors` (it might actually be `sortDescriptor` can't remember off the top of my head). You also bind the selection index in the same manner. This will allow the array controller in the detail nib to keep up with what is going on in the list nib, after that you just bind each detail element as normal (i.e. the product name text field would have it's value bound `arrayController.selection.productName`. 
If you forget to bind the sort descriptor of the detail nib's array controller to it's counterpart in the list nib the detail nib will update each time the selection changes in the list, but it might not change to the proper product (the binding just passes the selectionIndex not what object is selected).

Comment: I get this error, actually: `[<NSArrayController 0x10061cca0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key selection.`

Comment: Did you remember to `@synthesize` the property or make your own accessors? Should also check to make sure the outlet is connected.

Comment: so basically you want two instances of NSArrayController to share the same content? The Product.nib only needs one instance and it's the selection.

Answer (score 0):

When allocating the view controller for the Product.nib you should bind its "product" property to your array controller's selection, it can only be done in code, but that will avoid the need for multiple instances of an array controller, and avoid the need to bind them together so they look the same.

Also, I suggest not to bind the array controller's content to your own NSArray, if you do not bind that property the array controller will allocate and manage its own array. You'll be able to add/remove objects from it directly instead of having to rely on your own property to carefully notify the NSArrayController that a change occurred.

The "content" binding is there to allow to bind an array controller's arrangedObjects to the content of another controller to be able to filter and sort the content differently.